# How to step next input?

Tags: jquery, forms

this is my html structure

```
<input type="text" class="name1" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" class="name2" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" class="name3" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" class="name4" tabindex="4">
```

if I fill current input it must step next input how can be possible ? I have no any jquery code to do and any idea

Comment: how do you expect to step next input "characters may be long"? On entering only one char?

Comment: one or more or with format (calendar,age,characters long etc.) it just be fill :))

Comment: Then how do you expect the user has entered the full text in input?

Comment: what do you mean ? as I know if-else or something like that

Comment: @fortherest . what is the exact length of text which user going to put in the input ,,,,  Is it always fixed??

Comment: I'm trying to understand just how can be possible to improve myself it's not nessessary but I wonder it..and I forgot to tell my input format must be calendar (jqueryui,another else) whenever I click my input date calendar will be opening

Answer (score 2):

To step next input ,  You can use [**.focus()**](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

`$(".name2").focus();`

to step to `name2` textbox
Or

`$(".name3").focus();`

to step to `textbox` `name3`

In what condition it should step up , that you need to decide.

for Eg: if text length limit is 8 then ,

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 8)
{
     $(this).next().focus();
}
});
```

> and  to know how to use calender input  Use datepicker . [Click
>   here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)